# C# Bind ADODB.Recordest to TextBox

Tags: c#, data-binding, com-interop

I have an application that was migrated from a legacy app, and for now we want to keep it using the COM ADODB classes (using Interop).

In the original app we had a TextBox control bound to one of the fields in the Recordset, but now I cannot see how to do this.

This is what I'm trying right now:

txtBox.DataBindings.Add("Text", recordset, "FieldName");

But this leaves the textbox blank.

I know the recordset has data because I'm also binding a datagrid control to the same recordset and it shows several records.

Any ideas?